# DataGridView cell formatting loses decimal precision in value

Tags: excel, vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview, number-formatting

I have a two-dimensional Double array used to populate a DataGridView.  The default formatting for the cells is N1, thus, the original value of 1393.832900298831 will be displayed as 1,393.8.

My problem is that the value in the grid really ***is*** 1393.8 and not 1393.832900298831.

Essentially, I want to emulate Excel's behavior for displaying/editing cells.  When the user enters the "editing mode" for a cell, I want 1393.8 to revert back to 1393.832900298831.

The CellFormatting event isn't helpful because I **do** want the formatting to occur in the aftermath of a value change.

I attempted to use the CellBeginEdit event to set the cell value to the array's value but literally nothing happens.  I must be missing something or barking up the wrong tree!

```
'This is initialized/populated elsewhere
Protected rInputValues(,) as Double

Private Sub DgvInput_CellBeginEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs) Handles DgvInput.CellBeginEdit

    'This does nothing?  No error.  Just nada.
    DgvInput.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = rInputValues(e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex)

End Sub
```

SOLUTION FROM JIMI: Use the EditingControlShowing event.  WORKED LIKE A CHARM.

```
Private Sub DgvInput_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DgvInput.EditingControlShowing

    If (DgvInput.CurrentCell.Value Is Nothing) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    e.Control.Text = DgvInput.CurrentCell.Value.ToString()
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe not the ideal solution, could you handle the Cell OnEnter/OnLeave and remove/reset the formatting as required?

Comment: The Cell's value IS `1393.832900298831`, but you're using the Formatted Value. Use the `EditingControlShowing` event to set the Text of the TextBox (referenced by `e.Control`) to `[DataGridView].CurrentCell.Value.ToString()`. You can edit the actual value's representation; after editing, the value is reformatted as defined by the `Format` property of that Column

Comment: Thank you, Jimi, this is absolutely what I needed!  I will update my post with the code.